# visual studio code red squiggles

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

Gave up trying to solve this by myself. My visual studio code shows red squiggles through everything.

It can't find the System. classes, even though I did not uninstall .net and .net core SDKs and runtimes.

Weird is that it builds the project correctly and even runs it but it becomes impossible to work.[image]

Comment: Had the exact same problem. Seems it may occur if you have an out of date VS2017 installed as Omnisharp tries to use a VS installation for a better experience. See here for some options to fix the issue: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1855